# How can I calculate the mean of the cube of random variable that follows chi-square distribuion?

Tags: chi-squared-test, mean

If $X + 1 \sim \chi^2_{1}$, what is the mean of the cube of $X$?

I'm confused between raw moment and central moment.

My idea is, since the mean of $X$ is 0, I should calculate the raw moment.

However, I'm not sure about that because it's mean.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  I marked up your formula to render it in a more readable form, but in so doing I had to eliminate quite a lot of the original punctuation and I had to understand that $X$ doesn't have a chi-squared distribution; rather, $X+1$ does (for otherwise how could the mean be $0$?).  Please check it to make sure I didn't misinterpret your intention.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the cube out using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) gives you:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X^3) 
&= \mathbb{E}((X+1-1)^3) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}((X+1)^3 - 3(X+1)^2 + 3(X+1) - 1) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}((X+1)^3) - 3 \mathbb{E}((X+1)^2) + 3 \mathbb{E}(X+1) - 1. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Since $X+1 \sim \chi_1^2$ we now need the [raw moments of the chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Noncentral_moments), which are:

$$\mathbb{E}(X+1) = 1 \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{E}((X+1)^2) = 3 \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{E}((X+1)^3) = 15.$$

Substitution of these raw moments into the above equation gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X^3) 
&= \mathbb{E}((X+1)^3) - 3 \mathbb{E}((X+1)^2) + 3 \mathbb{E}(X+1) - 1 \\[6pt]
&= 15 - 3 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 1 - 1 \\[6pt]
&= 15 - 9 + 3 - 1 \\[6pt]
&= 8. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any error with effects on the result;
> mean((rchisq(1e7, 1)-1)^3)
[1] 8.026047

Comment: @Pete: Well, I suppose a lot of mathematicians would bristle at the idea that there is no error in taking ```8.026...``` as an approximation of ```8```.  Surely there is an error of ```0.026...```, is there not?

Comment: My calculation is just a random sample. It's not expected to give exaclty 8.  If you prefer: t.test((rchisq(1e7, 1)-1)^3)    95 percent confidence interval:
 7.953115 8.047400

Comment: Okay, I see now.  Yes, you can certainly try to simulate the required moment, and that should indeed converge to the true value.  Still, it is interesting that even with $10^7$ simulated values you still only get two significant figures of accuracy.

Comment: Not so surprising: > sd(randomsample)
[1] 76.80253
> sd(randomsample)/sqrt(1e7)
[1] 0.02428709. Brute force simulations aren't very efficient. However, they are very simple to program and reasonably fast (a few seconds in an old desktop using R).

Answer (score 1):

For any random variable $X$, central moment = raw moment if $E(X) = 0$, because
$E(X^k) = E[(X-E(X))^k]$.

Let $Y=X+1$. Then $Y\sim \chi_1^2$, $E(Y)=1$, $X^3=(Y-1)^3$, So $E(X^3)$ = the third central moment of chi-square distribution with df = 1.